# Not Loading CSS File In Laravel From public folder

Tags: css, laravel, public

Not Loading CSS File In Laravel From public folder

i have all the css file in public folder and i also link them to my index but the css not working.

Comment: Have you added like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset('css/style.css')">

Answer (score 3):

Try using [PHP built-in webserver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) instead of artisan server
`php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` (run this command in the root of your Laravel project).

Also, you need to run `npm install && npm run dev` so that the default CSS and JS will be compiled. ([Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#installing-laravel-mix))

Answer (score 0):

You can access the public folder using asset (). Let's assume that there is a template folder under Public and a style.css file in this folder. If you use it as follows, your problem will be solved.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('template/') }}/style.css">
```